# Mathematical Operator over Boolean values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, boolean

Can someone explain what will be the order of execution of following JavaScript Code:

```
(true + false) > 2 + true
```

I understand using + operator over two Boolean values returns the result as 0,1 or 2 depending upon the values being provided.

I interpreted output of above code as 1 by breaking the execution in following order:

```
1) (true + false) // Outputs : 1
2) 1 > 2 // Outputs : false
3) false + true //Outputs : 1
```

But the actual result is:

```
false
```

Can anyone correct my understanding if am interpreting the code in wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a question of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), of three parts,

- `( ... )` [grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) with the highest precedence of 20,
- `+` [adition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) with precedence of 13, and
- `>` [greater than](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator) (here) with the lowest precendece of 11.

That means the operators with higer precedence are evaluated first and the comes the once with lower precedence.

```
(true + false) > 2 + true
(true + false)             -> 1
                 2 + true  -> 3

             1 > 3         -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `2nd` point is not correct.

```
1) (true + false) outputs - 1
2) (2 + true) - outputs 3
3) 1 > 3 - outputs false
```

You can check this using functions

```js
(true + false) > 2 + true

function f1() {
  const cond = true + false;
  console.log(cond);
  return cond;
}

function f2() {
  const cond = 2 + true;
  console.log(cond);
  return cond;
}

console.log(f1() > f2());
```

If you want to compare with 2 then add true, you must to wrap into the parentheses

```
((true + false) > 2) + true
```

Comment: So you mean first both  + operator will be executed then comparison will take place?

Comment: Yes, for the first example. The second will work inside parentheses than `+ true`